# php export var_dump values

Tags: php, explode

i have this result form a var_dump

```
$arr = explode("\n", $str);
var_dump($arr);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "Ìäíå ãÕÑí (EGP) "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(72) " 0.5358 1 Ìäíå ãÕÑí = 0.5358 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí 1 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí = 1.8664 Ìäíå ãÕÑí "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(72) " 0.5353 1 Ìäíå ãÕÑí = 0.5353 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí 1 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí = 1.8682 Ìäíå ãÕÑí "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) " 0.09 % "
}
```

i need to get each value in another array

$arr[0]="Ìäíå ãÕÑí (EGP) ";

$arr[1]=" 0.5358 1 Ìäíå ãÕÑí = 0.5358 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí 1 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí = 1.8664 Ìäíå ãÕÑí ";

$arr[2]=" 0.5353 1 Ìäíå ãÕÑí = 0.5353 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí 1 ÑíÇá ÓÚæÏí = 1.8682 Ìäíå ãÕÑí ";

$arr[3]=" 0.09 % ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the $arr to another array variable

```
$foo = array();
$foo = $arr;
```